# Downgrade from 10.5 to 10.3 mxd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mxd, compatibility

I use save as methods as well as MXD Doctor but nothing happening. I have previously 10.5 version and I have saved my work in MXD. Now I have 10.3.2 version. How can I open .MXD files?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please describe the precise and detailed steps that you perform to get to where you are stuck, and make clear what version of ArcMap and the MXD Doctor you use at each step.

Comment: There was no 10.3.2 release, just 10.3.1 then 10.4.0.